# Using Express and Body-Parser in a Google Cloud Function (NOT Firebase Cloud Function)

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions, body-parser

I am trying to get my head around using GCF and Express together.  All of the examples I have found give good info about Firebase CF but not straight up GCF.

Specifically, I need to use body-parser to get at some POSTed body info that is being sent via a content-type of 'x-www-form-urlencoded' rather than 'application/json'.  I can see the data if I console.log the req.rawBody but haven't found a clean way to get at the body parts.

I found this article: https://mhaligowski.github.io/blog/2017/05/15/serving-functions-express.html but to me it is just a couple of code snippets that really isn't clear on how things actually hang together.

Comment: Here [https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions] you can find some examples of express body-parser that may be helpful for your case

Answer (score 0):

You can require `body-parser` and as long as you send the `Content-Type: application/json` header, it will parse as JSON automatically:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

exports.acceptJson = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200);
};
```